# How to get values from matching column in a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets (`Variáveis` and `Indicadores`). In `Variáveis` there are 14 columns (col A-Codes, col B-Description, cols C:N-months from January to December) and in `Indicadores` there are 17 columns (col A-ID, col B-Description, col C-Formula, col D-Measurement Unit, col E- Info, cols F:Q- months from January to December).

`Variáveis` contains the `int` monthly values for each code.
`Indicadores` has a text formula (column C) composed by the codes stored in `Variáveis` (e.g. `(dAA11b+dAA12b)/dAA13b*100`) that is converted (with the code below that was developed with the help of @tigeravatar) into a excel formula by replacing the codes for his correspondent `int` monthly value (e.g. `(742+764)/125*100`).

Portion of Sheet `Variáveis`
[image: Variáveis]

Portion of Sheet `Indicadores` with formula already converted and result in the first month
[image: Indicadores]

**Note: this is just an example and values vary because I used the `=RANDBETWEEN()` formula to populate the worksheet with int values**

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsLookup As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim aLookup() As Variant
    Dim aData() As Variant
    Dim lCodesLookupCol As Long
    Dim lCodesConvertCol As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("Indicadores")
    Set wsLookup = wb.Worksheets("Variáveis")

    'This line loads the codes we need to lookup and their associated Int Value into an array
    aLookup = wsLookup.Range("A2:C1309")

    lCodesLookupCol = LBound(aLookup, 2)
    lCodesConvertCol = UBound(aLookup, 2)

    'This is the range containing the Formulas stored as text in data worksheet
    With wsData.Range("C2", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))

        'Loop through the lookup array and convert all codes into their associated Int Values using the Range.Replace method
        For i = 1 To UBound(aLookup, 1)
            .Replace aLookup(i, lCodesLookupCol), aLookup(i, lCodesConvertCol), xlPart, , False
        Next i

        'Now all of the Codes should have been replaced with their associated Int Values, but the formulas are still just text
        'This block will load the formulas as text into an array
        If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            aData(1, 1) = .Formula
        Else
            aData = .Formula
        End If

        'Loop through the aData array to prepend an = sign to convert them into formulas
        For i = 1 To UBound(aData, 1)
            'Verifies if the cell isn't blank and that it's not already a formula
            If Len(aData(i, 1)) > 0 And Left(aData(i, 1), 1) <> "=" Then aData(i, 1) = "=" & aData(i, 1)
            wsData.Cells(i + 1, 6) = aData(i, 1)
            If Left(aData(i, 1), 1) <> "=" Then
                MsgBox "Error @ row " & Str(i + 1)
            End If
            'On Error Resume Next
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Right now the code converts the text formulas in `Indicadores` into excel formulas by replacing the codes with their values (stored in `Variáveis`) and placing the result in the column desired (in this case it was col F- Jan)

At the moment the macro can only do the job for one month at a time. What I'm trying to do now is to do the same thing but for all months simultaneously. All help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hello @JohnyAbreu , I Think that Copy your issue then delete it + Paste it again will not help you to get the answer you need...

Comment: @JohnyAbreu , I meant that it should be better if you let your 1st post longer than create a new one...

Comment: I could have done that but since I ended up changing some parts of the code and made some corrections to the text (it was a bit confusing, still is but better now) I decided to delete the previous question and make a new one. Also I wanted to take the 'advantage' of people being more active at this time of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little obfuscated and over-engineered, but I think this is the line that actually writes your values to the output sheet:

```
wsData.Cells(i + 1, 6) = aData(i, 1)
```

In which case the number "6" is the column being written to, which makes sense since that is the "January" column in your output sheet.

What I would do is enclose the entire sub in a For Loop that runs 12 times (once for each month), and have it increment that number on each loop. Something like this:

```
Sub Looper()

For x = 6 To 18

    LookupMachine x

Next x

End Sub

Sub LookupMachine(MonthNum As Integer)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsLookup As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim aLookup() As Variant
    Dim aData() As Variant
    Dim lCodesLookupCol As Long
    Dim lCodesConvertCol As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("Indicadores")
    Set wsLookup = wb.Worksheets("Variáveis")

    'This line loads the codes we need to lookup and their associated Int Value into an array
    aLookup = wsLookup.Range("A2:N1309")

    lCodesLookupCol = LBound(aLookup, MonthNum - 4)
    lCodesConvertCol = UBound(aLookup, MonthNum - 4)

    'This is the range containing the Formulas stored as text in data worksheet
    With wsData.Range("C2", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))

        'Loop through the lookup array and convert all codes into their associated Int Values using the Range.Replace method
        For i = 1 To UBound(aLookup, 1)
            .Replace aLookup(i, lCodesLookupCol), aLookup(i, lCodesConvertCol), xlPart, , False
        Next i

        'Now all of the Codes should have been replaced with their associated Int Values, but the formulas are still just text
        'This block will load the formulas as text into an array
        If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            aData(1, 1) = .Formula
        Else
            aData = .Formula
        End If

        'Loop through the aData array to prepend an = sign to convert them into formulas
        For i = 1 To UBound(aData, 1)
            'Verifies if the cell isn't blank and that it's not already a formula
            If Len(aData(i, 1)) > 0 And Left(aData(i, 1), 1) <> "=" Then aData(i, 1) = "=" & aData(i, 1)
            wsData.Cells(i + 1, MonthNum) = aData(i, 1)
            If Left(aData(i, 1), 1) <> "=" Then
                MsgBox "Error @ row " & Str(i + 1)
            End If
            'On Error Resume Next
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Note that I extended the aLookup array to cover up to column N, and changed the column number in the Array lookup from a hardcoded "2", to "MonthNum - 4", which should increment the column of data it's working with in the way that you want.

Comment: Yes, you're correct that's the line that prints the result in the output sheet. Some people did suggested me to implement a loop before the ```aLookup``` array and I did not think of this way you just suggested.
Going to test it out and will give you feedback later.

Comment: I ran the code with the changes you suggested but something's not right. It replaces the formulas with the codes values until the last month as supposed (December) but when printing the result to the output sheet it just calculates this same last month and it puts it in the January column. Also returns me error "Runtime error '9': Subscript out of range"

Comment: I think the problem may be on these 2 lines ```lCodesLookupCol = LBound(aLookup, MonthNum - 4)``` and ```lCodesConvertCol = UBound(aLookup, MonthNum - 4)```. After the error I replaced ```MonthNum - 4``` for 2 (as it was before) and now the code ran without errors but it printed the December results to all columns (from Jan to Dec).

Comment: So by changing that, you changed the data lookup from the array from dynamic to static, which is why you get the same result in all columns. You need to have two incremental numbers in there for it to work properly. I think using an array here is overkill, and makes it very complex to debug. Good luck!

Comment: I've managed to solve the problems since last time i replied here. ```lCodesLookupCol = LBound(aLookup, 2)```and ```lCodesConvertCol = UBound(aLookup, 2)``` stayed like that while in ```.Replace aLookup(i, lCodesLookupCol), aLookup(i, MonthNum - 3), xlPart, , False``` i replaced ```lCodesConvertCol``` for ```MonthNum - 3```. Running perfectly now, thank you.

Comment: Glad you were able to find the solution. Good luck with your future VBA coding :)